# Why does WCF endpoint address change every time?

Tags: wcf, endpoint

I'm new in WCF

Why every time I run this service it's run on a different address and not run in address I wrote?

I'm sorry if this is very easy :(

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="PBServiceBehavior" name="PhoneBookService.PbService">
      <endpoint name="PbHttpEndpoint" 
          address="http://localhost:9001/PhonebookService" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="PhoneBookService.IPbService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="PBServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your WCF service is hosted by IIS or the built-in web server (Cassini) in Visual Studio, your configuration is **not** being used.

Instead, the *virtual directory* you've defined in IIS (where the `*.svc` file exists), or the dynamically defined  (and possibly changing) address used by the built-in Cassini web server in Visual Studio will determine your endpoint address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to check this setting
[image]